# Pager JS parameters and Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, pager

I'm using Pager JS, Knockout and Jquery in my web application. Here's the code

```
function ViewModel(){
  var self = this;

  self.interior = ko.observable();
  self.interior.background = ko.computed(function() {
    $.getJSON('/interiors', {interior_id:  self.interior_id()}).success(function(data) {
      return self.interior.background = data.interior.background_url;
    });
  }, this);

}

$(document).ready(function () {

  pager.Href.hash = "#!/";
  viewModel = new ViewModel();
  pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  pager.start();

});
```

When the code is executed I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<ViewModel> has no method 'interior_id'
```

I understand that the variable does not exist yet, and she do not have a method. But how to get around this error?

Comment: Don't call a non-existent function? What do you want to do?

Comment: So I want to do - when the parameter 'interior_id' changes, from JSON page fetch data and update the 'interior' variable. Maybe you have any suggestions?

Comment: But you don't even have a property or observable in your view model called 'interior_id'?

Comment: Yes. I don't. This parameter created by PagerJS inside the view-model when Pager is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `interior_id` gets added to your viewmodel later then you can use the `deferEvaluation` option on your `ko.computed` so it only evaluates its function when the `background` property gets accessed and not when your `ViewModel` is created:

```
self.interior.background = ko.computed(function() {
    //do stuff
}, this, {deferEvaluation: true});
```